# vBulletin CSS & HTML

Tags: php, html, css, vbulletin

I've been trying to set up my user-rank images into CSS sprites.. and I've worked out so far this code:
in additional.css:

```
#ranks li {
    background: url(/rank-sprite.png) no-repeat top left;
}
.sprite-admin{ background-position: 0 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-banned{ background-position: -207px 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-bugabuser{ background-position: -414px 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-coder{ background-position: -621px 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-donator{ background-position: -828px 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-exdonator{ background-position: -1035px 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-hondonator{ background-position: -1242px 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-legdonator{ background-position: -1449px 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-member{ background-position: -1656px 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-middleman{ background-position: -1863px 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-moderator{ background-position: 0 -94px; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-mudkip{ background-position: -207px -94px; width: 150px; height: 50px; } 
.sprite-newcomer{ background-position: -407px -94px; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-pikachu{ background-position: -614px -94px; width: 150px; height: 50px; } 
.sprite-recoverer{ background-position: -814px -94px; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-robot{ background-position: -1021px -94px; width: 150px; height: 50px; } 
.sprite-snorlax{ background-position: -1221px -94px; width: 150px; height: 50px; } 
.sprite-superdonator{ background-position: -1421px -94px; width: 157px; height: 44px; } 
.sprite-unicorn{ background-position: -1628px -94px; width: 300px; height: 100px; }
```

for the actual rank:

But it doesn't work.. it always displays the .sprite-admin{ background-position: 0 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; }  one.. which also is the top left one.

Have I done something wrong? Or does it sound like something to do with vBulletin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
#ranks .sprite-admin{ background-position: 0 0; width: 157px; height: 44px; }
```

Because the power of `#ranks li` is greater then single Classes like (.sprite-admin etc). So, we have to increase the power of sprite Classes to override the properties.

**OR**

You can do other thing. Write like this:

```
li {
    background: url(https://data.bugabuse.net/images/sprites/rank-sprite.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

instead of this :

```
#ranks li {
    background: url(https://data.bugabuse.net/images/sprites/rank-sprite.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

Comment: It's better you can define images in CSS :after & :before pseudo Check this for more http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Comment: Is there anything I can add to the CSS so that it wont create the new lines?

Comment: are you want text not to come in new line?

Answer (score 0):

Dont set background position  ranks li

```
#ranks li {
        background: url(https://data.bugabuse.net/images/sprites/rank-sprite.png) no-repeat;
    }
```